# Firebase functions not triggered on Database write

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this firebase function which is properly deployed for testing on Firebase :

```
exports.testDataPoint = functions.database.ref('/testDataPoint/{uid}/{id}/')
    .onCreate(event => {
        if (event.data.exists()) {
            return admin.database().ref("/test/"+event.params.uid+"/accumulate")
            .transaction(current => {
                return (current || 0) + event.data.val();
            })
        }
        else{
            return Promise.resolve(true)
        }
    });
```

When I try to write a data of **10000** entries at once the function is not triggered at all. But if the number of entries is around **1000**, function triggers perfectly.
Here is the script I'm using to write data:

```
function testGroupWrites() {
    let users = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        let id = shortId.generate();
        let jobs = {};
        for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            let uid = shortId.generate();
            console.log(uid);
            jobs[uid] = 1;
        }
        users[id] = jobs;
    }
    db.ref("testDataPoint")
        .set(users)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("written");
        })
}
```

Is there any limit to how much data can be written at a point above which function will not gets triggered? I'm testing this scenario, because in my project firebase function will be doing the same thing to calculate values.
I'm using *Admin SDK* in my script to write dummy data.

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a limit, please check the below:

[image]

So the maximum is 1000 entries, more info here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits